# MySQL query across 2 databases with different users

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that joins data across 2 databases and inserts new records into one of the databases.  The query below works if the same mysql user has access to both databases and both are on the same server. However, how would you re-write if each database has different user credentials?

PHP Script snippet:

```
$hard = mysql_connect($hostname_hard, $username_hard, $password_hard) 
        or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

# Insert artists:
mysql_select_db($database_hard, $hard);
$query_artsync = "insert ignore into {$joomla_db}.jos_muscol_artists 
                   (artist_name, letter, added,url,class_name)  
                 select distinct 
                   artist
                   , left(artist,1) as letter
                   , now()
                   , website, artist 
                 from {$sam_db}.songlist 
                 where (songtype='s' AND artist <>\"\")";
mysql_query($query_artsync, $hard) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<br>Artist tables merged! <br><br> Now merging albums<br><br>";
```

So..in the above the `{$sam_db}` database is accessed by a different user than the `{$joomla_db}` user...
There are more complex inserts following this one, but I think if I can get the above to work, then I'll likely be able to apply the same principles to the other insert queries...

Answer (score 1):

you're talking about using 2 different connections in the same query, which, unfortunately, is not possible.  what you'll have to do is get (select) all the information you need from the one database, and use that info to construct your insert query on the other database (2 separate queries).

Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT artist, LEFT(artist,1) AS letter, now() as added, website
  FROM {$sam_db}.songlist
  WHERE (songtype='s' AND artist <>\"\"", $sam_con);
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) != false)
{
  $artist = mysql_real_escape_string($row['artist']);
  $letter = mysql_real_escape_string($row['letter']);
  $added = mysql_real_escape_string($row['added']);
  $website = mysql_real_escape_string($row['website']);
  mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO {$joomla_db}.jos_muscol_artists 
    (artist_name, letter, added,url,class_name)
    VALUES
    ('$artist', '$letter', '$added', '$website', '$artist')", $joomla_con);
}
```

where $sam_con and $joomla_con are your connection resources.

Comment: Hmm...how would I do that? Theoretically - I follow you... programmatically, I'm not sure how to do it...I can do the select subquery separate ran by one user connection:

user1 query:
    select distinct artist, left(artist,1) as letter, now(), website, artist from {$sam_db}.songlist  where (songtype='s' AND artist <>\"\")

But then how to I read the results of user1's query into the user2's  query?

Comment: -1 Incorrect, you can combine data from as many databases as you want, anyway +0, because your code will work, but you're pinging the DBserver twice, where once with a user with the proper grants is enough.

Comment: @Johan not if you can't access them both with the same user, as stated in the question

Comment: the question was "how do I do this with 2 users" not "how do I update my users to do this". Thanks for the undownvote

Comment: @hairraisin, you create a third user that is allowed to do the combined query. It does not add any security to have two separate users that only have access to one database each, if you are going to combine that data anyway, and it slows the database server down and your php server has to work extra.

Comment: @Johan I don't disagree with you, except that I think your solution falls outside the scope of the question. Perhaps OP is not the DBA and doesn't have access to grant privileges.  Though I will admit I may have inferred too much from the phrase "The query below works if the same mysql user has access to both databases _and both are on the same server_" [emphasis mine]

Comment: @hairraisin, in **that** case getting the data out of the DB and back in is the only way, I'd still rather go with a blackhole-trigger though, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP for example, you will have to create 2 unique mysql instances, 1 per connection.

Then use both and do individual queries.

Explanation...

Setup connections to both databases using `mysql_connect` for example. Now, you now have defined the connenction variables...

In the `mysql_query` you apply those variables, e.g `mysql_query($query, $connect1)` or `mysql_query($query, $connect2)`.

From there you can extract and insert using code.

Comment: @Johan, guess you can go back to trolling for more posts to -1, as you did the one above this and where wrong :)

Comment: A: I disagree with the `you will have to` part. B: the answer is to short to be useful C: It really only makes sense with your comment. I'll be happy to upvote you if you put **that** in the answer, but as it stand it's more of a comment than an answer in itself.

Comment: I edited it, but i believe i am right with the you will have to... You cant run it unless the permissions are set up a certain way, it is two unique databases, with 2 unique users, which have seperate permissions... Anyhow, i digress :) moving on!

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem querying tables from different databases.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM db1.table1 a
INNER JOIN db2.table2 b ON (a.id = b.id)
```

Will run with no problems, as will your insert query.
**However** the user that starts the query needs to have proper access to the databases and tables involved.

That means that user1 (who does the insert) has to be `grant`ed insert+select rights to table `{$joomla_db}.jos_muscol_artists` and select rights to `{$sam_db}.songlist`

If you don't want to expand the rights of your existing users, then you can just create a new `inserter` user that has the proper access rights to use both databases in the proper manner.
Only use this user to do inserts.

**Alternative solution without adding users**
Another option is to create a blackhole table on db1 (the db you select from)

```
CREATE TABLE db1.bh_insert_into_db2 (
  f1 integer,
  f2 varchar(255),
  f3 varchar(255)
) ENGINE = BLACKHOLE;
```

And attach a trigger to that that does the insert into db2.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_bh_insert_into_db2_each ON bh_insert_into_db2 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO db2.table2 (f1,f2,f3) VALUES (NEW.f1, NEW.f2, NEW.f3);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The insert into table `db2.table2` will happen with the access rights of the user how created the trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html